# How to log errors which should never happen

Tags: logging, error-handling

There are errors, that should never occur. E.g. you put something to a map and when getting it then you don't expect to get NULL.

Still there are could be flaws in the code, which will result in impossible things happening. If we are talking about building robust system, such things should be checked upon, but there is no known cure - if you will also think what to do in imposible cases, complexity of the system can grow extremelly.

Still getting an impossible error is obviously a major issue, which should be logged. But with what level? Warn/error/fatal? And should it be separate file for impossibles?

Comment: The level of the error message shouldn't depend on how likely an error might happen but how badly the error should affect your application. Impossible errors should be handled just like any other error in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that error **never** happen, then if despite of your expectations happened, then you should report it as internal error in your code. If it happens, that means that something wrong in your business logic that caused failure of your expectations.

Also you should leave a comment that error is impossible, and it's handling just formal procedure.